# Sharepoint adds unwanted punctuation to URL's in calendar list item

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-calendar, list-item

Sharepoint adds all sorts of Sharepoint calendar list item unwanted punctuation such as “&” to URL’s and there are not very useful.

**Example:**

```
https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl
```

actually becomes:

```
https&#58;//www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl
```

Is there any quick work around?

Comment: Have you made some customization in calendar list? Try to create a new calendar list and compare whether the issue exists.

Answer (score 0):

*One answer I received form a colleague who is very knowledgeable about Sharepoint is:*

That is it encoding parts of the URL that can’t normally be represented.

https://www.url-encode-decode.com/

This will decode correctly on the above site.

Unfortunately, this isn't very user-friendly.

If anyone has a better way or better answer, please post.